# Error :String was not recognized as a valid DateTime (Formating) in C# 4

Tags: c#, string, datepicker

I have a datepicker in my c# application that provide strings like these:

> "2016/1/1"
>
> "2016/11/15"

But I want to change them to these formats:

> "2016/01/01"
>
> "2016/11/15"

I use this code:

```
    string searchstring = " and ProductStartDate Between '" + 
    String.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", Convert.ToDateTime(calender_from.Text)) + 
    "' and '" + 
    String.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", Convert.ToDateTime(calender_to.Text)) + "'";
```

but when I run following error occurs :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Any idea?

Comment: You should forget all that parsing/converting and use parameters instead. That would be less error prone

Comment: BTW DatePicker.DisplayDate already has the DateTime value you are looking for

Answer (score 3):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact` instead of `Convert.ToDateTime`:

```
calender_from.Text = "2016/1/1";

DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(calender_from.Text, "yyyy/M/d", null);
```

Then you can do this:

```
string searchstring = " and ProductStartDate Between '" + String.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", date) + ...
```

Comment: What's your basic string input format: `yyyy/M/d` (2016/1/1) or `yyyy/MM/dd` (2016/01/01)? You must commit yourself to one format. Otherwise it would be difficult to handle that.

Comment: Then use `yyyy/MM/dd` in `Datetime.ParseExact` or what's your problem?

Comment: is not working good. when i searching for example: between 2016/01/01 and 2016/12/01 - is not working and answer is null

Comment: When I changed it to `DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(calender_from.Text, "yyyy/MM/dd", null);`          Gives the same error  :                                                                                         **An unhandled exception of type System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll**                                  

**Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.**

Comment: Again, does `calender_from.Text` looks like `2016/01/01` or `2016/1/1`?

Comment: look like 2016/1/1

Comment: Then use `yyyy/M/d` in `DateTime.ParseExact`. I think your problem is in the formatting for the database condition, right? Maybe your database field expects a different format than `String.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", date)`. But that's not the topic here. If that's the problem, search StackOverflow or post a new question. Again to make it clear: `DateTime.ParseExact` makes a `DateTime` out of `string`. `String format` formats your `DateTime`-object for your output to a `formatted string`.

Comment: tnx for help me

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer is correct, please accept it.